# "Consistent gets" is higher when query is executed for the first time

Tags: oracle

I have the following query which when executed for the first time returns "consistent gets" 628066. When I re-execute it it return consistent gets as 270923.

The table itself has 272446 blocks (taken from `ALL_TABLES`).

It goes for a table scan in both cases and there are no indexes on the columns.

Any reason ? Is the statistics lookup adds to the consistent gets when executing for the first time.

```
select count(*)
from TABLENAME
where BEGDATE <= to_date('2018-03-01 09:00:00' , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') and
      ENDDATE > to_date('2018-03-01 09:00:00' , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
```

Here is the plan

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |                |       |       | 37516 (100)|          |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |                |     1 |    16 |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| TABLENAME      |    18 |   288 | 37516   (1)| 00:00:02 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: is it the same session?

Comment: Yes..it is in the same session..does it make a difference?just curious

Comment: Show us output of `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor('your_sql_id', null));` please

Comment: Added the execution plan

Answer (score 0):

It was due to dynamic sampling in oracle 12c